# iOS Bluetooth UUID changes after a few app launches on 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an app that connects to a CC2541 over Bluetooth Low Energy.  I simply want to cache something unique to each device so a user only connects to "their" device.  I've tried using

```
- (NSArray *)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers
```

and even scanning and comparing the UUID's of the scanned peripherals, but I have to select a newly generated UUID every few app launches.  The same code worked well on 8.1 and I rarely (if ever) had to select a new UUID.

I've debated checking the System ID (2A23 uuid) in the Device Information service, but that requires a connection to check the address so I'd have to connect to each nearby peripheral, get and compare the System ID, then either stay connected or disconnect and check the next one.

The CC2541 code I'm running isn't using pairing and I'd like to keep it that way.  I'm curious if anyone else has found a solution to this situation.

Comment: I don't know anything about IOS. So ignore this if it doesn't make sense. But why can't you use the Bluetooth MAC address? The MAC is guaranteed to be unique and you must have it as you can't communicate to the remote device without it. So I'm assuming IOS will have some API to get that.

Comment: According to the BLE standard, the MAC is NOT guaranteed to be unique and is supposed to change over time. And, Apple's framework does not pass the MAC through to your client code.

Comment: @CuriousRabbit Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for teaching me something today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been down this road, spending weeks to find a work-around to the limitations, the only way I have found is if you have control over the hardware and can put your own unique identifier in the advertising packet. While one can make all kinds of assertions about the (in)sanity of this, it is what it is.

Comment: Yea I've already been debating making that change for new devices that I make, but wanted to do something that would cover the devices that are already in customers' hands.  Oh well.  Thanks for confirming that this is the sad truth.  I love iOS development, but there is definitely something to be said about the more "open" nature of Android.

Comment: The reason of hiding MAC (or any other persistent identifier) from the programmer is to prevent tracking, in a similar way as it is done with WiFi MACs: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/06/ios8-to-stymie-trackers-and-marketers-with-mac-address-randomization/

Comment: @MichałCiuba - you're talking about rotating MAC addresses which is not the same as hiding the MAC address from the programmer. It's when the iOS device actually changes the MAC address it presents on the radio, in order to prevent other devices tracking it. The programmer never gets a look in.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post some code here that may help others in the future.

Put this somewhere outside of a function:

```
__xdata __no_init uint8 BT_MAC_ADDR[6] @ 0x780E;
```

Put this in your advertData array:

```
7, //length of data
GAP_ADTYPE_MANUFACTURER_SPECIFIC, //Custom data
0,0,0,0,0,0,  //Placeholder bytes
```

And finally update the advertData before you call GAPRole_SetParameter.

```
uint8 advertSize = sizeof(advertData);
memcpy(&advertData[advertSize-6], BT_MAC_ADDR, 6);
```